# Swipe of Side Menu Bar using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am trying to add a swipe for my side menu bar,

1. In my code I have a click method along with that I need a swipe technique too.
2. I need to remove the inside image of the side bar when it is opened and on click of document it should close the side menu bar and the list icon should appear back again.

Javascript:

```
$("#openMenuLayout").click(function(e){
      debugger;
            if ($('#menuLayout').hasClass('open-menu')){
          $('#menuLayout').removeClass('open-menu');
                $('#openMenuLayout').find('img').removeClass().addClass('open');


        } else {
          $('document, #menuLayout').addClass('open-menu');
                $('#openMenuLayout').find('img').removeClass();

        }
        e.preventDefault();
      });
$(document).click(function(e){

    if (!$("#menuLayout").is(e.target) && $("#menuLayout").has(e.target).length === 0) { 

           // Clicked outside, close menu
            $("#menuLayout").removeClass('open-menu');

    }

    });
```

Html:

```
<div id="menuLayout">
    <a href="#menuLayout" id="openMenuLayout">
        <img class="open" src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/32/Timeline-List-Grid-List-icon.png' />
        <img class="close" src="http://seotobiz.com/images/icon_close.png" style='display:none;'/></a>
    <nav id="menuLayoutList">
      <ul>
        <li>
            <form id="search">
              <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#homeLayout">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aboutLayout">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#KeyLayout">Key Facts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#teamLayout">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contactLayout">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Here is the demo Link that I have tried so far:

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/WDqZ2/9/)

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely be easier to use a swipe plugin like touchswipe http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/

As for the image, why don't you simply use a .hide() or .show()?